# forcing read_csv to read a predefined number of rows, while maintaining location of NA

Tags: r, tidyverse, missing-data

I have a csv file with leading NA, NA's in the middle, and in addition I want it to read a specific number of rows while placing lagging NA's.

For example:

Let's say my csv has 10 leading NA's, 3, NA, 5.

if I write:

```
df = read_csv("test1.csv")
```

I get the following:

```
df = data_frame(x = c(3,5))
```

The parameter "skip_empty_rows = F" yields something even more strange:

```
df = structure(list(x = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 5)), class = 
c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -26L), spec = 
structure(list(
cols = list(x = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

So two things are wrong here: One, it skips two places between the 3 and the 5 instead of only one, Two, it decides on its own how many rows to fill with NA in the end.

How can I force it to: 1) keep the same original NA's in the same places as the original, 2) Fill NA's in the end such that the length of the column will be predefined as I want?

Comment: I think you meant to write "columns" instead of "rows."

Comment: @keithpjolley No, I didn't....

Comment: There's nothing in your question about rows. Some sample input/desired output would help.

Comment: It is in my sample. My sample contains one column and varying number of rows.

Comment: Whatever. You say it's "predefined" but you don't say how it's defined. You don't mention what criteria you want to filter rows with and you don't explain why you it should skip one NA but not two NAs. If everything's predefined then plug those definitions into your filter and you are done.